# get all options in a select element with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a list of strings with all the values of the

Here is my html:

```
  <label>Select Roles</label>
    <span id="dualselect" class="dualselect">
        <select name="RolesSelect" id="dualSelectRoles1" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <option value="">Avaliable Roles</option>
        </select>

        <span class="ds_arrow">
            <span class="arrow ds_prev">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="arrow ds_next">&raquo;</span>
        </span>

        <select name="select4" multiple="multiple" id="dualSelectRoles2" size="10">
            <option value="12">Users Roles</option>
        </select>
    </span>
```

Here is my JS:

```
   <script>
function submitForm() {
    var arr = new Array;
    $("#dualSelectRoles2").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(arr);
}
</script>
```

My alert is displaying nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the option elements, then iterate over them:

```
var arr = new Array;
$("#dualSelectRoles2 option").each(function () {
    arr.push(this.value);
});
alert(arr);
```

Also, you can replace `$(this).val()` with `this.value`. You don't need a jQuery object here.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/VD2zD/)**

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
  var arr = new Array;
$("#dualSelectRoles2 option").each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val());
      alert(arr);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W28re/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the option elements within the select, then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
function submitForm() {
    var arr = $("#dualSelectRoles2 option").map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    alert(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/22/

you need to run loop through  each option.

```
 var arr = new Array;
    $("#dualSelectRoles2 option").each(function () {
        arr.push(this.value);
    });
    alert(arr);
```